# How to nest for loops recursively and efficiently in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, for-loop, tree, functional-programming

I'm new to this website, and i thought you could help me with something i just can't figure out.

I need to nest for loops recursively and find a way to push in an individual array the complete path for all single leaves at the center of my for loops.

In other words, i need to do something like

```
var link2 = function(node,nb){
var array =[];
//getAnwers returns an array containing the leaves of the node.
var array1 = getAnswers(node);  
        for(var j =0;j<getAnswers(node).length;j+=2){     
            var array2 = getAnswers(array1[j]);
            for(var k = 0;k<array2.length;k+=2){
                var array3 = getAnswers(array2[k]);
                for(var l=0;l<array3.length;l+=2){
                    var arraytemp = [];
                    arraytemp.push(mot);
                    arraytemp.push(array1[j]);
                    arraytemp.push(array2[k]);
                    arraytemp.push(array3[l]);
                    array.push(arraytemp);
                    print(arraytemp);
                }
            }
        } return array;   
    }
}}
```

But in a recursive way!
I tried by doing something like this, where nb is the number of recursions.

```
var link6 = function(node,nb){
var array = [];
var arraySave = [];

var helper = function(node2,nb,arrayTemp){//pause();
    if(nb<=0){

        for(var k=0;k<arrayTemp.length;k+=2){
            var arrayChain = [];
            for(var j=0;j<arraySave.length-1;j++){
                arrayChain.push(arraySave[j]);
            }
            arrayChain.push(arrayTemp[k]);
            if(k===arrayTemp.length-2){
                arraySave.pop();
                arraySave.pop();
            }
            array.push(arrayChaine);
        }
    }

    else{
        var array1 = getAnswers(node2);
        for(var i =0;i<array1.length;i+=2){
                arraySave.push(array1[i]);
                helper(array1[i],nb-1,array1);
                return array;
            }   

    }
}
helper(node,nb,null);
return array;
```

}

The question is, how can I do the SAME exact thing i do in my first code, but in a recursive way so i can chose the number of levels my tree has! I tried as you can see with the function link6 but didn't manage to obtain good results.... I'm quite a beginner..

Thank you very much!

Comment: The `if..else` chain you have going on there will never get past the first `else` because it will `continue` the loop. Try to make the example code less localised; there are so many functions you use but haven't defined. Also, `var` inside loops D: Furthermore you may find [_named function expressions_](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#named-expr) useful, but beware they symbol bleed on IE8-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tip: Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array = [];
getAnswers(mot, seuil).forEach(function(jarr) {
  return getAnswers(jarr).forEach(function(karr) {
    return getAnswers(karr).forEach(function(larr) {
        var arraytemp = [mot, jarr, karr, larr];

        print(arraytemp);
        array.push(arraytemp);
    });
  });
});
```

And as [Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s) pointed out in his comment, you probably don't mean to use `continue` in all those else branches.

To answer your original question, I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
/* Assumes that n >= 1 and depth(arr) > n */
function ndeep(arr, n, fn) {
  function helper(acc, n) {
    arr.forEach(function(narr) {
      var nacc = acc.slice();
      nacc.push(narr);

      if (n == 1) {
        return fn(nacc); 
      } else {
        return helper(nacc, n - 1);
      }
    });
  }

  return helper([], n);
}

var array = [];
ndeep(getAnswers(mot, seuil), depth, function(acc) {
    array.push([mot].conat(acc));
});
```

... where `depth` is your desired depth.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! Yeah the continue statements were an error. I've edited the codes I've posted so they're easier to understand.